# When running terraform init, the following error is displayed

Tags: terraform

When running terraform init, the following error is displayed:

```
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/azurerm: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to
│ request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http:
│ request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded
│ while awaiting headers)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something wrong. Any specific network connection settings or something? Would you mind sharing the Terraform code you are using?

Comment: It's a simple test example:
"terraform {
  required_providers {
      azurerm = {
        source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "~>2.0"
      }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}"

It was the same with aws

Comment: Hi Oleg - can you even access this URL in your browser on the same machine: https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json ?

Comment: Hi KJH! Yes, i can. There are two strings:
"modules.v1 "/v1/modules/"
 providers.v1 "/v1/providers/""

Comment: is this resolved? I am facing similar issue.